# Can't connect to postgresql "Role does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to connect to postgresql from a docker container but I get following error:

```
2019-03-02 20:10:45.218 MSK [2777] spectrum_user@spectrum_db FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "spectrum_user"
2019-03-02 20:10:45.218 MSK [2777] spectrum_user@spectrum_db DETAIL:  Role "spectrum_user" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host  all     all     172.17.0.0/16       md5"
```

Looks like it successfully connects but fails to authenticate. And I don't have idea why. I can connect to db with psql. This role definitely  exists.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Does anyone have suggestions?

UPDATE: It appeared that I had two versions of postgresql running simultaneously and I tried to connect to wrong postgresql instance.

Comment: How is postgres hosted? Is it sitting in another docker container or on a linux system?

Comment: Could you please share docker command?

Comment: postgresql is running on main system not in a container.
docker command: docker run --name="spectrum2" -d --restart unless-stopped -v /opt/spectrum2/configuration:/etc/spectrum2/transports -v /opt/spectrum2/data:/var/lib/spectrum2 spectrum2/spectrum

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database from outside of the docker container? Have you tried connecting with another user?

Comment: I can connect to my db with psql outside of container. I tried to create new user and tried to change owner of database to postgres but ended with the same result.

Comment: The issue is with postgres. You have to adjust the conf to accept external connections.

Comment: If you add a tag for your operating system, and/or add info to the question description, I'll create an answer telling you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: @DavidKamer As you can see there is a line in pg_hba.conf which is printed in logs. So it should accept connection from docker containers.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that I had two versions of postgresql running simultaneously and I tried to connect to wrong postgresql instance.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to edit the pg_hba.conf.

On my install of Ubuntu 18.04 this is the path:

```
/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
```

You can try:

```
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
```

replace vim with your choice of text editor. If a file doesn't open with this command (a file that already has settings in it) then you'll need to explore around /etc/postgresql to find the pg_hba.conf file. Try:

```
find -name pg_hba.conf
```

Once you find and open the file, edit the following lines:

Under the comment `# IPv4 local connections:`

```
host    all             all             172.17.0.1/24           trust
```

Now you'll need to edit one more file:

```
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
```

Change any reference of `listen_addresses` to:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

After you've saved all the above changes, run this command:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

**Note: this configuration isn't secure for a production environment, and you would need to configure your firewall and change some of these settings to make it secure. This is for development only.**

Now, as long as you're pointing at your host OS's IP address for your postgres URL and the user exists on the system and the role exists in the database, you'll be able to connect to the host database from the docker container. I also always bind an HTTP port, so this may come into play. I'd need to see your docker file to give any information on that.

You also need to allow the port on your firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow from 172.17.0.1/24 to any port 5432
```

If you don't care about security and the above still doesn't work, just open port 5432. Be aware that opening a port can be unsafe.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried that. Postgres is listening on right IP address:

postgres  29754        postgres    7u  IPv4 23513310      0t0  TCP 172.17.0.1:5433 (LISTEN)

I tried to change md5 to trust but got the same error :(

Comment: @Marzanna I added information on how to adjust your firewall. You should probably adjust it for only the ip of your docker container, but the above will work for all docker containers.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't have any firewall restrictions. I noticed that postgresql was listening on different ports. 5432 for localhost and 5433 for 172.17.0.1 (WTF!?). There was default value port=5433 in postgresql.conf. I changed it to 5432 and restarted postgresql. It was listening on correct port. But I failed to connect even from localhost! I can't login with another username which used to work previously. I changed port back to 5433 but I still can't connect. Something is definitely wrong with postgresql.

Comment: run `sudo -i` then connect to your system user like `su username` where username is the name of the user in postgres and on your system. run `psql -d databasename` from there and you should be able to connect and see what's going on in postgres.

Comment: Thank you again but I solved this issue. I updated the question.